# Adding REGEX entities to SpaCy's Matcher

Tags: regex, spacy

I am trying to add entities defined by regular expressions to SpaCy's NER pipeline.  Ideally, I should be able to use any regular expression loaded from a json file with a defined entity type.  As an example, I am trying to execute the code below.

The code below shows what I am trying to do, following an example given on Spacy's discussion about custom attributes using regular expressions.  I have tried calling the 'set_extension' method in various ways (to Doc, Span, Token), but to no avail.  I'm not even sure what I should be setting them to.

```
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
    pattern = [{"_": {"country": {"REGEX": "^[Uu](\.?|nited) ?[Ss](\.|tates)$"}}}]
    matcher.add("US", None, pattern)
    doc = nlp(u"I'm from the United States.")
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
       span = doc[start:end]
       print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

I expect `match_id, string_id 3 4 United States` to be printed out.

Instead, I am getting `AttributeError:  [E046] Can't retrieve unregistered extension attribute 'country'.  Did you forget to call the 'set_extension' method?`

Answer (score 5):

There's documentation around the extension attributes here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes

Basically you'll have to define this `country` variable as an extension attribute, something like this:

```
Token.set_extension("country", default="")
```

However, in the code you cited you're never actually setting the `_.country` attribute to any token (or span), so they're all still at default value, and the matcher will never be able to get a match on them. The line you cited:

```
pattern = [{"_": {"country": {"REGEX": "^[Uu](\.?|nited) ?[Ss](\.?|tates)$"}}}]
```

Tries to match the United States regex **on the custom attribute values**, instead of on the doc text, as you expect (I think).

One solution is just to run the reg-exps on the texts directly:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^[Uu](\.?|nited)$"}},
           {"TEXT": {"REGEX": "^[Ss](\.?|tates)$"}}]
matcher.add("US", None, pattern)
doc = nlp(u"I'm from the United States.")
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

Which outputs

> 15397641858402276818 US 4 6 United States

Then you can use those matches to e.g. set a custom attribute on the Span's or Token's (in this case Span, because your match is potentially involving multiple tokens)

Comment: Could you paste the full code and new error after putting the code line I cited right before declaring the `pattern` variable? I'm assuming it's going to be a different error, then we can work from there.

Comment: I already tried that.  I've set `Token/Doc/Span.set_extension` both before and after the `pattern` variable.  In both cases, I get a `TypeError: expected string or byte-like object`.  Moreover, the page for the link https://spacy.io/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes doesn't exit.

Comment: Hi, Sophie VL.  I don't know how to copy the code from my initial question.  But as I said above, whether I place `Token.set_extension("country", default=True)` right before or after the `pattern` variable, I get the same error.

Comment: The page I cited in my original answer has a /usage/ part in the URL and does exist  - the URL you cite is different and non-existing

Comment: Thank you so much, Sofie VL.  That does work, and I simply had no idea how to fix the error that I was getting.  Now I can try out other regular expressions to get a better feel for what is going on.  However, I would have liked a solution that didn't require me to change the input regular expression since I want to be able to handle any regular expression that is given, without having to parse it first to accommodate SpaCy's way of handling it.  But, at least I have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

As already said at [How to use standard regex with SpaCy's Matcher or PhraseMatcher while allowing spaces inside the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56711352/11154841), the answer that checks each token cannot work with any RegEx that has embedded spaces since the tokens are already split by spaces.

In other words, the tokenizer splits the data into tokens so that the RegEx cannot match any embedded spaces anymore, which gives you two workarounds:

1. You might try running your RegEx on your own tokenization. Tokenize by sentences instead of words. Then check for your RegEx patterns. Put that output as a full text again into spaCy pipeline. You might even try adding this as a step in the pipeline right before tokenization.
2. Another workaround could be to check whether neighboured words that you link together inside the main loop over all tokens (with a link back to the two other words before) match a pattern of up to three words (=with up to two embedded spaces). If you find something, overwrite all of the three matches with markers that you map in a dictionary against the needed marker. After the run, you can then replace such matches with just one match, if needed. You might also find another way to do this without a mapping table, this is just a first thought, you might even change the match already on the run during the loop.

Since RegEx becomes slow on a large text, you should tokenize at least by sentences before running RegEx on it, and I guess that the workaround "2" with word tokenization and the backwards checking loop is easier and faster than the RegEx check on the sentence tokens since the pipeline would then stay as it is. A three times backwards checking loop should not take much speed. I did not test this since I found it easier to rewrite the RegEx with spaces as a list of regexes without spaces, see Stack Overflow [Can a Named Entity Recognition (NER) spaCy model or any code like an entity ruler around it catch my new further date patterns also as DATE entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77724359/11154841).