# How to use standard regex with SpaCy's Matcher or PhraseMatcher while allowing spaces inside the regex

Tags: python, regex, spacy

I'm still trying to find a most general approach, that given a standard regex (as recognized by Python or Java), that I can pass to spaCy's Matcher or PhraseMatcher without having to preprocess it first into a SpaCy-format-like "REGEX".

I've already asked a more specific question at Stack Overflow [Adding REGEX entities to SpaCy's Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533422/adding-regex-entities-to-spacys-matcher). [Sophie VL answered with a good, workable approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539083/11154841), but it required breaking up a regex with embedded `\s+` into separate match tokens. I've tried to use PhraseMatcher, but it doesn't seem to accept arbitrary "REGEX" patterns. I'm repeating the example I gave in my earlier query of June 11th, 2019.  Perhaps there is a way to give a standard regex using custom attributes, but I haven't been able to find the right approach.

```py
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    pattern = [{"ORTH": {"country": {"REGEX": "^[Uu](\.?|nited) ?[Ss](\.|tates)$"}}}]
    matcher.add("US", None, pattern)
    doc = nlp(u"I'm from the United States.")
    matches = matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
        span = doc[start:end]
        print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

As stated before, I expected `match_id, string_id 3 4 United States` to be printed out. I know now I should use PhraseMatcher or a custom attribute, but haven't figured out quite how yet. I just want to say that Sophie's answer did help me get some regex patterns that don't include spaces or hyphens. I am still grappling with the documentation on PhraseMatcher and custom attributes, but am on deadline, so I am again posting this question.

Comment: I presume you know what `^[Uu](\.?|nited)[ ]?[Ss](\.|tates)$` can  match.

Comment: Yes, been dealing with standard regexes in Python, Java, Perl, bash, etc for a while.  Not claiming perfection, but adequate familiarity.  But, don't really see the need for the empty `[ ]`, when I really want is `\s+`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding REGEX entities to SpaCy's Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533422/adding-regex-entities-to-spacys-matcher)

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of your other question even if you tell here that it is just on top of the other and this question put here only to speed up. In that other question, you also ask for a RegEx that allows embedded spaces: " Ideally, I should be able to use any regular expression loaded from a json file with a defined entity type."